# Should a method always be static in component when suggested?

Tags: angular, webstorm

Sometimes it happens that WebStorm suggests me to make a method static inside a component even if this method is called inside the template.
[image]

Sometimes this suggestion is valid but, in these specific cases, I do not understand if it is really useful.
I enter an example below. In these cases, is this suggestion correct? Is there a way to turn the method into static (or something else) and call it from the template? If the suggestion is invalid, how do I deactivate the suggestions for static methods?

Component class:

```
  public sections = [
    {
      title: 'Section 1',
      desc: 'Description section 1',
    },
    {
      title: 'Section 2',
      desc: 'Description section 2',
    }
  ];

  public trackByTitle(index, item) {
    return item.title;
  }
```

Template:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let section of sections; trackBy: trackByTitle">
    {{section.title}} - {{section.desc}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-static-methods-webstorm-trackby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It's only a suggestion and it is based on WS's best practices settings. It's not required, but if possible you should try to take their advice (again - ONLY if possible). In most cases, it will improve your code cleanliness and quality, but you should also be aware that they analyze your code without really understanding the context. Which means that in some cases it can break your program. So try to follow their guideline, but don't feel obligated to

Comment: Definitely a wrong suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm not a web storm user and cannot help you with that.

Comment: I'm also not a web storm user. Does the `more actions...` link give you an option to suppress the suggestion there?